# Replacewhere in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have saved a dataframe as a delta table partitioned by [customer,site,machine,date] in overwrite mode and replacewhere by date>=value1 and date<=value2:

```py
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite') \
  .option("replaceWhere", date >= '2022-04-01' and date < '2022-04-02') \
  .partitionBy([["customer", "site", "machine", "date"]]) \
  .format('delta').save(output_filepath)
```

When I execute the statement twice (first run for customer1 and second run for customer2), then the customer1 data is getting overwritten by customer2 for 2022-04-01.

So I in repleacewhere clause I have added customer( '`(date >= '2022-04-01' and date < '2022-04-02') and (customer.in(['customervalue']))'`)
I am getting error  AnalysisException : Cannot recognize the predicate.
What are the other possible ways I can overwrite only for a particular customer and for particular date.

Thanks in adavance!!

Comment: Can you try this code? `option("replaceWhere", "date >= '2022-04-01' and date < '2022-04-02'")`